# Equality like Pascal triangle

Tags: combinatorics, mathematical-physics, combinatorial-proofs, algebraic-combinatorics

I have noticed the following is true. 
Let's denote the equation below as (1)
$$\sum_{k=1}^{d+1}(-1)^{d+1-k}\frac{1}{(d+1)(k-1)!(d+1-k)!}\prod_{i=1}^{d+1}\Big(\frac{q}{h}+(k-i)\Big)\prod_{j=k}^{d}\Big(1-jh\Big)\prod_{\ell=d-k+2}^{d}\Big(1+\ell h\Big).$$

Let's denote the equation below as (2) 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{d}(-1)^{d-k}\frac{1}{(d)(k-1)!(d-k)!}\prod_{i=1}^{d}\Big(\frac{q}{h}+(k-i)\Big)\prod_{j=1}^{d}\Big(1+(k-j)h\Big).$$

If I replace $q\, \text{by}\, \frac{1}{x-1}$ in eq(1)

and $q\text{by}\, 1/x$ and $h\,\text{by}\, \frac{(x-1)h}{x}$ in eq (2) we have tested for few values of  $d$

$(x-1)^{d}\, eq(1) = x^d \,\text{eq (2)}$

Can I have a proof of this fact? Any help or why is true? 
Notice that eq (1) has $d+1$ terms and eq(2) has $d$ terms. So its seems like pascal triangle any combinatorial viewpoint?

Comment: What do you mean by, "... we have ..."? I wouldn't write "we have" unless I had a proof, but since you are asking for a proof, that can't be what you mean by "we have". So, what do you mean?

Comment: Sorry I have just done the computation for few values. I have the change the phrasing. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: What are $h$ and $q$ in equations $1$ and $2$? Are they integers, rational numbers, real numbers, complex numbers, polynomials, or something else? Also, what is $x$ in $q=\tfrac{1}{x-1}$? Lastly, how can you set $h=\tfrac{(x-1)h}{x}$ in equation $2$?

Comment: Also, how are the parentheses placed around the products in equation $(1)$? Do you take the two products over $j$ for every value of $i$, or is it a product of three distinc products? That is to say, is it
$$\prod_i\left(\prod_j\cdot\prod_j\right)\qquad\text{ or }\qquad \left(\prod_i\right)\cdot\left(\prod_j\right)\cdot\left(\prod_j\right).$$

Comment: $q$, $ h$, $x$ are all algebraically independent variable. Maybe you can replace then by $h=(x-1)/xh'$ My claim is the expression would be the same. They are all distinct product I edited it. Thanks for your comment

Comment: What's the origin of these expressions?

Comment: For what values and how exactly did you test the equality? I'm not sure If I re-typed it correctly, but I do not get an equality when substituting some values.

Comment: In the first equation, $\ell$ ranges from $d+2-k$ previously I wrote $d-k+1$. I think you can check it will all be equal. I have checked more d from 1 to 30.

Comment: The origin of the expression is dealing with some Montone Hurwitz numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a partial answer; it gives a [computer-aided](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html) proof (yes, the identity holds true).

Some cleanup first. We have
$$\prod_{j=k}^{d}(1-jh)\prod_{\ell=d-k+2}^{d}(1+\ell h)=\frac{\prod_{\ell=-d}^{d}(1+\ell h)}{\prod_{j=1}^{d+1}\big(1+(j-k)h\big)},$$
so that $(1)$ equals
$$\frac{\prod_{\ell=-d}^{d}(1+\ell h)}{(-h)^{d+1}(d+1)!}\sum_{k=0}^{d}(-1)^{d-k}\binom{d}{k}\prod_{j=0}^{d}\frac{(q/h)+k-j}{(-1/h)+k-j}.$$
Now, if we do all the suggested substitutions, denote $a=1/\big((x-1)h\big)$ and $b=-1/h$, and retain the (common) notation $\binom{x}{n}=\frac{x(x-1)\ldots(x-n+1)}{n!}$ for real $x$, we see the following needed to be proven.

> Let $$F_d(a,b)=\sum_{k=0}^{d-1}(-1)^k\binom{d-1}{k}\binom{a+k}{d}\binom{b+k}{d},\\G_d(a,b)=\sum_{k=0}^{d-1}(-1)^k\binom{d-1}{k}\binom{a+k}{d}\Big/\binom{b+k}{d}.$$ Then $$F_d(a,a-b)=(-1)^{d+1}\binom{2d+1}{d}\binom{b+d}{2d+1}G_{d+1}(a,b).\tag{*}$$

I don't see an "elegant" proof yet. But the book linked above suggests methods to find recurrences satisfied by $F_d$ and $G_d$, via "telescoping" recurrences satisfied by the summands. Specifically, in our case we find
$$d(a-b-d-1)(a-b+d+1)F_d(a,b)\\+(d+1)(2d+3)(a+b)F_{d+1}(a,b)\\+(d+1)(d+2)(d+3)F_{d+2}(a,b)=0$$
(using a computer) and
$$(d-1)(d+1)G_d(a,b)\\+(2d+1)(b-2a)G_{d+1}(a,b)\\-(b-d-1)(b+d+1)G_{d+2}(a,b)=0.$$
Now it's easy to verify that $(\text{*})$ holds for $d\in\{1,2\}$, and that both sides of it satisfy the same recurrence.

Comment: The book mentioned the use of package also I can see telescoping series algorithm. Is there any way I can put (*) in maple and verify directly? How do you derive the recursion? Using package or by hand?

Comment: Regarding the direct verification of (*) - indeed, one can put it into a single sum; gonna try it myself once I get back (I don't have Maple installed on my personal machine). Yes, I've ended up using the package, after initial results from WA.

Comment: Thanks update me if you have success What is WA?

Comment: Well, nope. Although it "eats" both sides of $(\text{*})$ apart. To get the above, I load [this](http://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/tokhniot/EKHAD) (via `read`) and issue $$\texttt{zeil((-1)^k*binomial(d-1,k)*binomial(a+k,d)*binomial(b+k,d),k,d,D)}$$ and the like. (Just in case you try it too.) WA is Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: You save the EKHAD as text file in maple folder? It keep complaining can read file.

Comment: Store it anywhere you like, and give `read("...")` the full path (under Windows, double the separators, e.g. `"D:\\Path\\To\\EKHAD"`, and better avoid spaces).

Comment: @metamorphy: Nice approach. (+1)

Comment: I got the same recursion for F_d and G_d as yours but how would you conclude the recursion are same? OR RHS satisfies the same recursion as LHS?

Comment: No worry I put into the whole expression on RHS it gives me the answer

Comment: @GGT Substitute $d\mapsto d+1$ and $G_{d+1}=R_d/(\ldots)$, etc. into the recurrence for $G_d$ (where $R_d$ is the RHS; this is what I did by hand initially).

Comment: I was missing $d\righrarrow d+1$. Thanks again.